# I am receiving and import error when trying to import cv2 in python (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: python, opencv, import

First of all, thank you very much for reading.

Some days ago I installed Python3 (3.6.9) and opencv 3.4.10 in an Ubuntu 18.04 desktop system. I needed to downgrade opencv to 3.4.0 after some compilation problems  (not related to python3), so I removed opencv 3.4.10 by using the `sudo make uninstall` order, and tested that it was uninstalled as if I tried importing it in python I got the following error:

```
libopencv_hfs.so.3.4: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
```

I thought installing 3.4.0 version would solve the problem but now that it's installed, when I try to import it in a python3 script I am getting the same error. I think this error must be related to the way python3 references the import files. I think it's still pointing to the uninstalled version of 3.4.10, but I can not find the way to change it.

Could someone please help me with this issue?

Thank you very much.

Andrés.

Comment: do you compile it ? can't you install with `pip` like `pip install opencv-python` or try `pip install opencv-python==3.4.0`?

Comment: If you go the pip route, I think you'll want to use pip3 to install for Python3.

Comment: I compiled it as I need it as dependences for CUDA and Darknet.

Answer (score 0):

Using a virtualenv would resolve the issue. Check this out on how to use : [Installing packages using pip and virtual environments](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#:%7E:text=virtualenv%20is%20used%20to%20manage,can%20install%20virtualenv%20using%20pip.)

Once you're done installing requirements in the virtualenv, run your python script there only to use the specified versions.

Comment: I'm using virtualenv. The easiest way would be create another Virtual Environment and use it, but i wanted to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hello again and thank you for you answers.

I have been able to solve the problem. Thought I had uninstalled the previous version of opencv, there was still a `cv2.so`file in my python virtual environment path, and it had not been replaced by the new `cv2.so`, so python tried to import the old one instead of the new one.

The old `cv2.so` (the one that was referenced when I imported cv2 in python) was here --> `~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so`
The `cv2.so` I wanted to be used when imported was here --> `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/cv2.so` so I replaced the one in the virtual environment path with the one in the lib directory and that did the trick :)